# Connecting legacy c++ application with BDE(borland database engine) to Oracle 19 enterprise

Tags: database, oracle, oracle19c, borland-c++, bde

I recently updated our database to oracle 19 enterprise and our legacy application which uses Boraland c++ and BDE(borland database engine) is not able to connect to the database.

Oracle locks the user account out of the database so we know that it is able to connect to Oracle because oracle eventually locks the user account that is trying to connect.

Is there any settings in oracle 19 that we could consider changing so it allows BDE connection? Its almost like oracle is saying BDE is so old we don't trust you.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?  What version of the Oracle client are you using?  My guess would be that the older database didn't enforce case-sensitive passwords, the new database does, and the application is trying to use a password with the wrong casing.  If it was a compatibility issue between the version of the Oracle client and the Oracle server, you wouldn't generally get a failed login.